# Does an offline installer for SP1 of Windows Server 2008 R2 exist?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, setup

Does an offline installer for SP1  of Windows Server 2008 R2 exist? I need to install it on a host not connected to Internet

Thank you

Comment: Of course there is.  [Its just in the form of an .ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842).  You can also just download the single installer if you want.